# Calculating probability from a Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, density-function

Is it possible to calculate the probability of a continuous variable from a probability density function without integrating to find the CDF?

I have a PDF $$f(x) = \begin{cases}3x^2 & 0 \le x \le 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I can calculate $P\left(X\le \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ by integrating to find the cumulative density function, but I have been asked to calculate it without a CDF. Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Best to just calculate $\displaystyle\int_0^{1/2}f(x)\, dx$ to get the answer. (Surprised if that is not allowed)

Comment: Isn't integrating finding the CDF?

Comment: Without integration, there are infinite numbers and infinite possibilities, so it just would not be possible. If you really cannot use direct integration, try approximating rectangles to find area under the graph from $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ (not the most accurate though).

Comment: To me, "finding the CDF" would mean finding $P(X\le x)$ for a general $x$. For this question, we are just finding $P\left(X \le \frac{1}{2}\right)$ (which is evaluating the CDF at $x=\frac{1}{2}$).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. The answer was simpler than I thought. Nothing about the method. All about the representation of the CDF so you can ask questions like $P\left(X\le \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$.

The answer should be in the form:

$$F(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x \lt 0 \\x^3 & 0 \le x \le 1 \\ 1 & x \gt 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: I don't understand how this isn't using the cdf, though.

Comment: It's the difference between asking the question of the PDF and integrating versus creating a paramaterised CDF that you can just hit with the question. I think it would be more obvious if there were more than one function of x that made up the piecewise function. In the end the question stemmed from the wording of an assignment that I was trying to interpret.